# How to group by a column without aggregate?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-order-by

I have a table "table1 "that looks like below for example that contains data on donations like donation pledges and their payments etc. These will include pledges, their pledge payments, and also individual payment donations like shown in the last 3 rows:

```
ID     Type            Amount     Date             ParentID       Application
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
10     Pledge          50000      1/2/2020         50             Donation
20     Pledge          20000      5/2/2019         100            Donation
30     Payment         10000      2/1/2020         50             Pledge
40     Payment         15000      3/2/2020         50             Pledge
50     Payment         25000      4/5/2020         50             Pledge
60     Payment         10000      5/9/2019         100            Pledge
70     Payment         10000      6/8/2019         100            Pledge
80     Payment         5000       10/5/2020        200            Donation
90     Payment         9000       12/5/2019        250            Donation
100    Payment         8000       1/1/2020         230            Donation
```

I am trying to order by Date in DESC order like the following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1
ORDER BY 
    Date DESC, 
    CASE WHEN Type = 'Pledge' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END DESC,
    CASE WHEN Type = 'Payment' AND Application = 'Pledge' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END DESC,
    Amount
```

This seems to return the desired results, but I also want to make sure that all related transactions are always grouped next to each other.

For example, all related transactions will always have the same `ParentID` as seen in the table sample. I have tried adding a `GROUP BY ParentID` before the `ORDER BY` clause, but I get an error "not contained in an aggregate function".

Is there any other way without using GROUP BY so that I am able to ORDER BY in the same way I currently have it, but also add in the logic to ensure all related transactions based on the ParentID are always grouped next to each other?

Desired results are shown below. Basically the pledges should always be first, then their corresponding payments after in date desc order. Any individual payments not related are then in desc order of Date:

```
    ID     Type            Amount     Date             ParentID       Application
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    10     Pledge          50000      1/2/2020         50             Donation
    50     Payment         25000      4/5/2020         50             Pledge
    40     Payment         15000      3/2/2020         50             Pledge
    30     Payment         10000      2/1/2020         50             Pledge
    20     Pledge          20000      5/2/2019         100            Donation
    70     Payment         10000      6/8/2019         100            Pledge        
    60     Payment         10000      5/9/2019         100            Pledge
    80     Payment         5000       10/5/2020        200            Donation
    100    Payment         8000       1/1/2020         230            Donation
    90     Payment         9000       12/5/2019        250            Donation
```

Comment: You don't want to `GROUP BY` (you're using that term in another sense that what it means in SQL), you *just*  want `ORDER BY`. Maybe `... ORDER BY parentid ASC, date DESC ...`? (Hard to tell exactly since you didn't post the desired result.)

Comment: That's not what `GROUP BY` does, the order of the rows is completely controlled by the `ORDER BY` if you want rows that have a relation to each other to appear next to each other, you need to define an `ORDER BY` that causes that.

Comment: You're misunderstanding `group by`, you simply need to sort by your ParentId column first.

Comment: Perhaps you can eliminate any confusion by providing the desired results

Comment: Your table looks to be denormalized: you should have a `Donation` table with a nullable foreign-key to `Pledge` table. Then you can just order by `PledgeId`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `parentid` in your `ORDER BY`.

```
...
ORDER BY parentid ASC,
         type DESC,
         date DESC
...
```

Comment: This does allow the rows to be close to each other that are related, but it throws the dates off. I'd still like for the dates to be in desc order first. I've updated my desired results to reflect this.

Comment: @jwalls91: Changing a question invalidating existing answers is considered rude. If an answer does solve your problem as posted, accept it and post another question for your new problem. And as a side note: It would make things easier to understand for a lot of people, if you used an unambiguous date format like YYYY-MM-DD instead of ??/??/YYYY -- what's the month, what's the day in that?